# SWFAddress: adding "/" char at the end of an URL via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, swfaddress

how can I add the `/` char at the end of the `URL` without force the user to write it?
I'm starting to work with `SWFAddress` using `JavaScript` and `jQuery` directly (without `Flash`) like [this wonderful site](http://irrland.sonntagskunst.de/).

So something like this:

```
http://mysite.com/section

// and after click to a specific <a ="#">button</a> get
http://mysite.com/section/#/sub-content

// instead of
http://mysite.com/section#/sub-content
```

I've started with this code to do it:

```
$(".time_dot, .time_year").click (function () {
    onClickEvent (this);
});

function onClickEvent (dom) {
    var timer = setTimeout (function () {
        SWFAddress.setValue($(dom).parent().attr("id"));
    }, 200);
    // do something else 
}
```

The `setTimeout` method is used to avoid the `<a>` button overwrite the `SWFAddress.setValue` method, but I don't know a way to change the `URL address` to `url.com/content#/...` to `url.com/content/#/...`.

How can I do that?

Comment: The URL is created by the btn id in this case, if I have <a id="contacts" href="#">Contacts</a> I'll set http://mysite.com/section/#/contacts like the site Irrland I've posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already said, you cannot change the URL without forcing a reload of the site. And I don't think you want that. *(but it depends on how `SWFAddress.setValue()` actually works, if it just keeps track of the URLs internally (without changing the browsers URL) then you can do it)*

But I wanted to give you an alternative for `setTimeout`:

```
$(".time_dot, .time_year").click (function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    onClickEvent (this);
});

function onClickEvent (dom) {
    SWFAddress.setValue($(dom).parent().attr("id"));
    // do something else 
}
```

With this you prevent the click event from bubbling up and also prevent the change the default action (which would be following the link).

See [*jQuery event object*](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/).

Comment: it's great, thankyou, I've saw http://irrland.sonntagskunst.de/ doing it but I don't know how it does exactly.

Comment: @vittorio: Which browser are you using? The URL already ends with a `/`. If you use Chrome, this will be hidden, but Firefox shows it. Just type `irrland.sonntagskunst.de` in Firefox and see what happens...

Comment: sorry, I've saw now in http://irrland.sonntagskunst.de/ only works if i don't change the url, so it can be done only if the url is allready set like thi http://irrland.sonntagskunst.de/ instead of http://irrland.sonntagskunst.de (without / then)

Comment: @vittorio: If you want to make URLs appear as you type them, you have to put them into backticks `\``. Like `\`http://example.org\``

Answer (score 1):

You can't change the "path" part of the URL without reloading the page. So, if you're at http://mysite.com/section, you can not navigate to http://mysite.com/section/#/sub-content without reloading the page.

Comment: It can be done with http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SWFAddress / http://www.asual.com/swfaddress/ and It's commonly used on Flash sites. I see the browser load for a millisecond but the page doesn't refresh.

Comment: @vittorio: The page you linked to says *SWFAddress uses the "hash" portion of the URL*. So everything **after** the `#` can be changed as you wish, but not before. If it really works then please give a link to website that does so.

Answer (score 0):

you mean like

```
$(".time_dot, .time_year").click (function () {
   setTimeout (function () {
         SWFAddress.setValue("/"+$(this).parent().attr("id")+"/");
    }, 200);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function fixUrl(url) {  
    return url.replace(/\/?$/,'/');  
}

//or

function fixUrl(url) {  
    return url.match(/\/$/)  
       ? url  
       : url + '/';  
}
```